# match regular expression using regex order, not string order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to extract a specific pattern from a string, and **if its not there** then extract another pattern.

The string in question may have both patterns in any order. Regardless of the order, I want the first pattern to take priority.

I know I could do this with multiple lines/`match` calls but I am wondering if it is possible to do this with a single `match` call.

```
var s1 = "hello A123 B456"
var s2 = "hello B123 A456"
```

I want to capture `A###` pattern first, **and only if its not there**, then capture the `B###` pattern

```
console.log(s1.match(/((A|B)\d{3})/)[1]); // A123
console.log(s2.match(/((A|B)\d{3})/)[1]); // B123 -- but I want it to capture the A123 first
```

Comment: regex start matching from left to right order then how will start matching A123 first? by the way you can use lookbehind or lookahead

Comment: That is why I am asking/posting here. I am wondering if their is a way to tell it to give precedence to the match pattern?

Comment: What about `^(?:.*(A\d{3})|.*(B\d{3}))`

Comment: I don't see how you can do it in a single match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with either of the following regex patterns:

```
^(?:.*(A\d{3})|.*(B\d{3}))        # pattern 1
^(?:.*(?=A)|.*(?=B))([AB]\d{3})   # pattern 2
```

---

### Pattern 1

#### Regex

Pros/Cons: Easy, but uses two capture groups

```
^(?:.*(A\d{3})|.*(B\d{3}))
```

How this works:

- `^` anchors it to the start of the string
- `(?:.*(A\d{3})|.*(B\d{3}))` match either of the following options

  - `.*` matches any character (except newline characters) any number of times (it's greedy so it'll match as much as possible)
  - `(A\d{3})` matches `A` followed by 3 digits

The second options is the same as the first, but this works with backtracking:

```
^(?:.*(A\d{3})|.*(B\d{3}))

hello B123 A456
^                  # anchor to the start of the string (to the location before the h)
                   # now attempt option 1 of the alternation: .*(A\d{3})
    .*             # match any character any number of times (greedy)
hello B123 A456    # this is what we currently match
                   # now backtrack to find A\d{3}
hello B123 A       # we found A, check to see if \d{3} matches
hello B123 A456    # pattern fulfilled; result you're looking for in group 1
```

#### Code

```js
s = ["hello A123 B456","hello B123 A456", "hello B123"]
r = /^(?:.*(A\d{3})|.*(B\d{3}))/
for (x of s) {
  m = x.match(r)
  if (m)
    console.log(m[1] || m[2])
}
```

---

### Pattern 2

#### Regex

Pros/Cons: Less comprehensible, but uses only one capture group

```
^(?:.*(?=A)|.*(?=B))([AB]\d{3})
```

How this works:

- `^` anchors it to the start of the string
- `(?:.*(?=A)|.*(?=B))` match either of the following options

  - `.*` matches any character (except newline characters) any number of times (it's greedy so it'll match as much as possible)
  - `(?=A)` ensures `A` follows the current position
- The second alternation is the same as above, but uses `(?=B)` instead
- `([AB]\d{3})` match `A` or `B` followed by 3 digits

#### Code

```js
s = ["hello A123 B456","hello B123 A456", "hello B123"]
r = /^(?:.*(?=A)|.*(?=B))([AB]\d{3})/
for (x of s) {
  m = x.match(r)
  if (m)
    console.log(m[1])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can achieve that by anchoring the preferred option to the start of the subject:

```js
re = /^.*?(A\d+)|(B\d+)/

test = [
  "hello A456 B123",
  "hello B123 A456",
  "hello A456 zzz",
  "hello B123 zzz",
];

for (t of test) {
  m = t.match(re)
  console.log(t, '=', m[1] || m[2])
}
```

A drawback is that you have two groups to choose from.

Comment: The `^` seems unnecessary.

Comment: `^.*(A\d+)|(B\d+)` is faster; @3limin4t0r `^` may be unnecessary, but it does improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve the result with a negative lookahead.

```js
var s1 = "hello A123 B456";
var s2 = "hello B123 A456";

const regex = /A\d{3}|B\d{3}(?!.*A\d{3})/

console.log(s1.match(regex)[0]);
console.log(s2.match(regex)[0]);
```

The above regex is saying, `A` with 3 digits or `B` with 3 digits if not followed by `A` with 3 digits.